# Javascript insert serialized object data into new object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this object

```
Function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.kill = function(){
        console.log(this.name + ' is now dead.');
    }
}
```

Then I do this

```
var Tom = new Person('Tom');
var SerializedTom = JSON.stringify(Tom);
delete Tom // figuratively, Tom doesn't exist anymore
```

And now I want to recreate Tom

```
var NewTom = new Person();
NewTom = JSON.parse(SerializedTom);
```

Basically this is what I want to do, but then the `kill` function is lost. My question is how can I insert the data from the serialized object into the new object while maintaining it's functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write methods that handle the serialization. This allows full control over the state of the class as well as the deserialization and avoids potentially copying over fields that aren't supposed to be members of your class.
It's a bit more effort than T.J. Crowder's solution, which is more dynamic, but it has more control and in my opinion is a cleaner approach. Both are fine, though.

```
function Person( name ) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.kill = function() {
    console.log( this.name + " is now dead." );
};

// static method on the class where you receive your JSON object
// and create the instance of Person and set it up
// the way you want.
Person.fromJson = function( json ) {
    return new Person( json.name );
};

var Tom = Person.fromJson( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( new Person( "Tom" ) ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no out-of-the-box answer. One option is to modify your `Person` object so it can accept a data object, and then copy everything on the data object:

```
function Person(data){
    var key;
    for (key in data) {
        this[key] = data[key];
    }
    this.kill = function(){
        console.log(this.name + ' is now dead.');
    };
}

// Usage
var Tom = new Person(JSON.parse(SerializedTom));
```

You can support both with a type check:

```
function Person(data){
    var key;
    if (typeof data === "object") {
        for (key in data) {
            this[key] = data[key];
        }
    }
    else { // assume string
        this.name = data;
    }
    this.kill = function(){
        console.log(this.name + ' is now dead.');
    };
}
```

Side note:

You can put `kill` on the prototype that `Person` assigns to instances:

```
function Person(data){
    var key;
    if (typeof data === "object") {
        for (key in data) {
            this[key] = data[key];
        }
    }
    else { // assume string
        this.name = data;
    }
}
Person.prototype.kill = function(){
    console.log(this.name + ' is now dead.');
};
```

Comment: You're gonna want to change `name` to `this.name` now, though.

Comment: What difference does it make if I put the function on the prototype `:/` Basically what I was asking was if `javascript` had something like `php`'s unserialize, which it apparently and unfortunately doesn't, I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: @php_nub_qq: If you put it on the prototype, all instances share the same copy of the function. If you create it within the constructor, each instance gets its *own* copy of the function. For a small number of instances you don't create and release a lot, it doesn't matter; if you're creating a large number (or creating and releasing a lot of them), creating unnecessary functions increases memory churn.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the useful information, that's something I wasn't aware of!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but wait a minute, I'm confused. If functions from the prototype are being shared then what is the difference between a prototype function and a static function?

Comment: A static function is attached to the class itself, i.e. you can't call it on an instance, but on the class. Prototype methods are still appear to be methods on the instance, just that they are shared. In particular, instance methods have access to instance members – static methods don't (since they are not part of any instance).